# Como converter caracteres em UTF-8 no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, estilo-de-codificação, notepad++

Em minha plicação web, estou usando um banco de dados MySQL que possui a tabela `EditableContent`.
Essa tabela possui o campo `content`, que é do tipo `text` e tem como formato de entrada `utf8-bin`.

No banco de dados os caracteres aparecem normalmente, porém ao buscar os mesmo e exibí-los via método `echo`,
os caracteres com acento são substituídos por    `�` .
Ao usar o metodo `uf8_decode($meu_texto)`, os mesmos caracteres são substituídos por `?`.

Em uma linha da tabela, os caracteres são mostrados normalmente, e em outra, apenas a parte inicial.

Obs. Estou usando a meta tag:

```
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'
```

E o conteúdo foi copiado para o banco do NotePad++, sendo que a formatação do arquivo estava como `Codificação em UTF-8(Sem BOM)`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problemas com codificação PHP em UTF-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95382/problemas-com-codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php-em-utf-8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vejamos..

O que os colegas @Marta e @Marcelo disseram é verdade. Porém, às vezes, pode ser que o servidor web utilizado não esteja configurado para repassar UTF-8 - mesmo que use o `<meta ../>` ou a função `header()` do PHP. Se for um host numa VM compartilhada, mesmo sendo pago (host barato/gratuito é garantia de ser assim), vais ter que pedir para o suporte do servidor alterar para você - já tive este problema. Tente isso se nada abaixo funcionar.

**1 - Por meio da tag no HTML**

No 'padrão' HTML 5, podes utilizar

`<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Nos padrões anteriores, podes utilizar

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

**2 - Por meio do PHP**

Você pode configurar a página pura em PHP e chamar, logo no início, a função

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

**3 - Checar a configuração das tabelas do banco**

Pode ser que charset ou collade não estejam UTF-8. Vale a pena conferir

**4 - Página em PHP puro sem `header()`**

Se a página for em PHP puro ou uma chamada Ajax de página em PHP puro e não houver um `header()` com o charset definido em ambos os casos, não vai estar configurado para UTF-8. Este provavelmente é seu problema. Mas de nada vai adiantar se o HTML não estiver em UTF-8 também, claro.

Nota: É válido para redirecionamentos também.

Answer (score 8):

Algumas coisas podem ajudar, como por exemplo

- salvar o arquivo mesmo com o encoding correto - no notepad++ por exemplo você consegue mudar o encoding do arquivo.
- colocar uma meta-tag de UTF-8 na página: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Geralmente só definir na página é suficiente.

Answer (score 7):

Boas, experimente o seguinte código abaixo para resolver o teu problema.

Introduza este código no teu php, onde tem a sua conexão a base de dados.

```
<?php
    //O tipo de caracteres a ser usado
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

   //Depois da tua conexão a base de dados insere o seguinte código abaixo.
   //Esta parte vai resolver o teu problema!
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
?>
```

Introduza esta linha no teu html como mostra o exemplo abaixo

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

**Exemplo em html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> <!--Introduza esta linha no teu html-->
            <title>Exemplo de Página</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como sabes se irá resolver o problema? Ele pode estar a usar PDO ou mysqli. Ideal é configurar isso no mysql

Comment: Tens razão nesse ponto mas a partida pela pergunta dele não parece que esteja a usar PDO... Também é uma opção, pode sim configurar no próprio MySql.

Comment: Independentemente do driver usado, esta é a única resposta que menciona que a conexão com o MySQL também precisa ser configurada como UTF-8. Falta ainda alguma resposta realmente completa à pergunta, por que você não complementa a sua mostrando tudo que precisa estar em UTF-8?

Answer (score 6):

Talvez ajude alguém, eu estava com problemas no AJAX.

Eu estava usando no php:

```
*header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');*
```

Mudei para:

```
*header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');*
```

Answer (score 3):

Além de tudo que já foi respondido, verifique se seu webserver está configurado para usar UTF-8 como encoding.

No apache, adicione ao seu arquivo de configurações a seguinte linha:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Em resumo, você precisa garantir quatro configurações:

1- Charset do `php.ini` (pode ser forçado via [`ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8')`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset))

2- Charset do banco de dados (collation do banco de dados `utf8_*`)

3- Meta-tag na saída do HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

O webserver/php tenta adivinhar a partir do encoding do arquivo, portanto é interessante manter sempre os arquivos como UTF-8 sem BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). UTF-8 com BOM gera erros com o PHP (envio prematuro do Header)

4- Configuração do webserver (pode ser forçado via `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`)

Answer (score 0):

depende da codificação que tá usando em cada passo, todas tem que estar configuradas com o mesmo padrão de codificação....

se o que a Marta disse não resolver, tenta usar utf_encode, as vezes a troca de encode pra decode gera o ?? em palavras acentuadas...