# Erro ao criar uma banco de dados MySQLi via PHP no WampServer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou com problema na hora de criar o banco de dados, na net achei pouco conteúdo sobre, só encontro como montar banco de dados pelo phpMyAdmin, mas é via *script* que quero criar.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","");

if($mysqli-> connect_error){
    echo "Não foi possível conectar.";
}

$create_db = "CREATE DATABASE 'my_db'";

if($mysqli->query($create_db)){
    echo "conexão bem sucedida";
}
else{
    echo "falha na conexão";
}

?>
```

O WampServer não aponta erros de sintaxe. Sempre tenho como resposta "falha na conexão", o que há de errado?

Comment: Você realmente vai acessar como usuário `root` e sem senha? Este é o `root` padrão? Ele realmente tem privilégio para fazer qualquer coisa no MySQL? Este `my_db` não existe mesmo? Tentou trocar o `'` pelo `\``? Você entende que aparece `falha na conexão` porque você mandou escrever quando a operação dá um erro? Então precisa ver qual o erro.  Já experimentou usar `mysqli::$error` para ver qual é a mensagem de erro que o MySQL está retornando?

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso! Se você utilizar o charset=utf-8 na sua página, mesmo que no banco os acentos não apareçam na página que você chamar os dados vão aparecer os acentos. Procure inserir os dados sempre da mesma forma para não dar conflito. Se por formulário sempre por formulário.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bem, batendo o olho vi alguns problemas em sua query.

1. Não é preciso colocar o nome do banco entre aspas simples.
2. Se o banco de dados já existir, ele retornará um erro como esperado. É preciso dar um `DROP` senão não será possível cria-la **(não faça isso em produção)** ou adicionar `IF NOT EXISTS` na sua query para evitar um erro caso a database já esteja criada.

Alterei seu código colocando mensagens de erro completas na hora de executar o script.

```
<?php

// MySQLi usando try catch
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

try 
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","");

    $mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;");

    echo "Database criada com sucesso!";
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Alguma coisa de errada aconteceu. Detalhes: " . $e->message;
}
```

Comment: Muito boa resposta, e realmente o Drop é um pouco perigoso, só uma dúvida, alguém sabe como setar o tipo de caracter, no caso UTF-8 para o banco de dados para não ter problema com acentos

Comment: vlw, vou pesquisar mais sobre isso

Comment: @leandro17br as respostas dessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29455/como-converter-caracteres-em-utf-8-no-php) podem te ajudar

Comment: Pra tabela toda: `CREATE TABLE teste ...
 id VARCHAR(45) ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8`

Comment: Achei curioso que alguém negativou as outras duas respostas (minha e outra já apagada) mas não negativou esta que faz uso de exceções de um jeito ruim. Ela engole todas as exceções possíveis mesmo que o desejo é só pegar a exceção gerada pelo MySQLi. Não que eu ache que isto mereça uma negativação (afinal funciona, o único problema é que está ensinando uma prática ruim para quem é leigo no assunto), mas ficou incoerente por parte de quem negativou as outras.

Comment: @bigown concordo que a exceção poderia ser mais específica, porém como não uso com frequência mysqli optei pela generica. Minha resposta foi negativada também só que o downvote foi retirado. Deixando registrado, eu já tinha votado positivamente em sua resposta: https://imageshack.com/i/pbaFPUnxp

Comment: @gmsantos eu conheço eu comportamento no site, você costuma ter coerência, não precisa se preocupar. E para deixar claro, não negativei ninguém aqui, nem por alguns minutos :) A questão da exceção: não é um grande problema em exemplos simples, mas é sempre bom ter essa ressalva.

Answer (score 8):

Eu criei isto e funcionou. Se você fizer o mesmo e não funcionar, você tem algum problema na sua instalação ou na configuração do MySQL. Só vendo o erro fornecido pelo MySQL para ter certeza. Mas possivelmente desta forma nem aconteça o erro. Há possibilidade ser apenas um problema de sintaxe, eu não usei o apóstrofe no nome no banco de dados.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","uma_senha_aqui");

if($mysqli-> connect_error){
    echo "Não foi possível conectar.";
}

$create_db = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db";

if($mysqli->query($create_db)){
    echo "criação ok";
}
else{
    echo "falha na criação:" . $mysqli->error;
}

?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Connection.php).

Mandei imprimir o  `$mysqli->error` para ter uma informação para trabalhar. Quando você apenas manda escrever que falhou, não sabe porque falhou e fica mais difícil resolver algum problema.

Comment: Quem negativou certamente sabe que tem algo errado na resposta. Podia dizer o que está errado. Se for o caso eu corrijo ou até apago a resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Basta você tirar as aspas simples que vai funcionar normalmente, seu código está coreto, com excessão dessas aspas.