# Ler ficheiro não mete os acentos

Tags: php, html, txt

```
if(isset($_GET['rf'])){

  $filename=$_GET['rf'];
  //$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$filename;
  //echo $path;
  if(file_exists("subs/" . $filename)){

       header('Content-Type: text/plain');
       //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);  <-- DOWNLOAD FILE
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("subs/" . $filename));
       header('Expires: 0');
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
       header('Pragma: public');

       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile(utf8_encode("subs/" . $filename));
  }
}
```

- ***Aparece sem acentos ao ler o ficheiro***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece me que faltou definir o `chatset` no `header` que define o `Content-Type`. O que significa que pode não estar a ser visualizado como `utf-8` ainda que tenha sido lido como `utf-8`

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29455/como-converter-caracteres-em-utf-8-no-php/29470#29470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não é somente o charset utf-8 que não esta sendo setado nos headers do php. O conteudo lido pela função `readfile()` naõ esta sendo convertido para utf-8. Para isso acontecer algumas mudanças devem ser feitas:

- remover o comando `flush` (evitar que o conteudo de `readfile()` seja impresso automaticamente)
- adicionar `ob_start()` para armazenar o conteudo de `readfile()`
- Por fim obter o conteudo de `readfile()` com ob_get_clean() e fazer o encode para utf-8

Juntando tudo fica:

```
...

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);  <-- DOWNLOAD FILE
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename) . ";charset=UTF-8");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

ob_clean();
//armazena o que for impresso por readfile
ob_start();

readfile(utf8_encode($filename));

//obtem o que foi impresso por readfile e faz o encode
echo utf8_encode(ob_get_clean());

...
```